# Laravel routes not working for forget password

Tags: php, laravel

My laravel route isnt working, when i use parameters in the url.
Actually the email got sent to the receiver, but when they click on the link, the token is sent in the url as parameter. But a different route is used,which displays another page.
This is my web.php

```
 Route::group(['namespace' => 'Auth'],function(){
    // Password Reset Routes...
    Route::get('password/reset', 'ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.reset');
    Route::post('password/email', 'ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
    Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset.token');
    Route::post('password/reset', 'ResetPasswordController@reset');
});
```

This route gets called
`Route::get('password/reset', 'ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.reset');`
But i want this route to work`Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset.token');`
So it displays different page as directed by above route.
What do i do?
Please Help!!

Comment: try switching both lines (put your password/reset/{token} route above the password/reset route)

Comment: i tried that, it isnt working

Comment: did you load in authentication routes with Auth::routes()? if so, they might interfere with the routes specified by you. (if not, then I don't know, sorry)

Comment: No, i have commented out`Auth::routes()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your route name of /password/reset to something else like this
To avoid confusion lets change this from

```
Route::get('password/reset', 'ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.reset');
```

to this

```
Route::get('forget-password', 'ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.reset.form');
```

So your route may looks like this..

```
 Route::group(['namespace' => 'Auth'],function(){
    // Password Reset Routes...
    Route::get('forget-password', 'ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.reset.form');
    Route::post('password/email', 'ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
    Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
    Route::post('password/reset', 'ResetPasswordController@reset');
});
```

Please note that i've changed the route name password.reset.token to password.reset.

I think laravel built in code uses route name 'password.reset' for this.

Answer (score 0):

Does this not work for you:

```
 Route::group(['namespace' => 'Auth'],function(){
    // Password Reset Routes...
    Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset.token');
    Route::get('password/reset', 'ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.reset');
    Route::post('password/email', 'ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
    Route::post('password/reset', 'ResetPasswordController@reset');
});
```

note the order of the get's

The general one should be after the specific ones.

Comment: This route `Route::get('password/reset', 'ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.reset');` is working, as i am using this to send the email, but when somone clicks on the link there, The route with token isnt working, its going again to `password.reset`

Comment: Exactly. Check what I wrote at the end of my answer.

Comment: Yes sir, i saw that. i changed that too. But its still not working. Do i need to run php artisan serve again?I have put the specific ones first. As you suggested

Comment: Now i deleted all the routes and only kept the one i want, its going to `404 NOT FOUND`. means the problem is something else, right?

Comment: 404 could be due to invalid token.. but yes, you should be debugging in all of the ways you can think of, as you best know your ENV..